# How to copy excel to ascii file in non tabular form with macro?

Tags: excel, file-io, vba

I am recieving an excel file with n amount of columns and I have to make a macro to copy only A to C columns and the number of rows is unknown. Also I have to export the data to an ascii file in a continuous form and not as a table. I found the following code at http://www.mcgimpsey.com/excel/textfiles.html:

```
Public Sub CharacterSV()
    Const DELIMITER As String = "|"
    Dim myRecord As Range
    Dim myField As Range
    Dim nFileNum As Long
    Dim sOut As String

    nFileNum = FreeFile
    Open "Test.txt" For Output As #nFileNum
    For Each myRecord In Range("A1:A" & _
                Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        With myRecord
            For Each myField In Range(.Cells, _
                    Cells(.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
                sOut = sOut & DELIMITER & myField.Text
            Next myField
            Print #nFileNum, Mid(sOut, 2)
            sOut = Empty
        End With
    Next myRecord
    Close #nFileNum
End Sub
```

However this is giving me output in tabular form. My experience is in c# I have very little experince in excel and totally new at VBA and macros, so if you can help on this I would be very grateful.

Edit:

The input includes column A first name column B last name and column C ID number and looks like this:

```
John    Smith   12345656
James   Doe     94848484
Jill    Miles   78475899
Frank   Young   48758599
```

The output should look something like this:

John    Smith   12345656
James   Doe 94848484
Jill    Miles   78475899
Frank   Young   48758599

Comment: what do you mean by "continuous form and not as a table"? give us an example, please.

Comment: Show us how the input could look and also how the corresponding output should look.

Comment: I edited the question including input and output example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (self-explanatory) should work for you. You may want to use different code to define the source range.

```
Sub cont_out()
    Dim rng1 As Range, cl As Range
    Set rng1 = Range("A1")
    Set rng1 = Range(rng1, rng1.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))

    Dim strPath As String
    strPath = "test.txt"
    Dim fnum As Integer
    fnum = FreeFile()
    Open strPath For Output As #fnum

    For Each cl In rng1
      Print #fnum, cl.Text & " ";
    Next cl

    Close #fnum
End Sub
```

Comment: Fulfills my needs perfectly! Thank you very much!